# How to model a 3D representation of the polynomial function

Tags: mathematics

I have the function of form `P≡y(x)=ax^7+bx^6+...+h`. How could I plot xyz function in Blender, so that 2D projection of that curve onto xy plane is function P ? That xyz function should look something like a park slide (more-or-less). I have already tried Math Function Mesh from Mesh : Extra Objects add-on. However, I haven't achieved anything useful.Furthermore the model is supposed to have specific thickness so that it can be printed later. Could somebody give me some tip how to achieve this.

Graph of function:
[image]

And Blender's graph:
[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT I:
I have used the following functions:
`y(u,v)=(7.0675*10**(-12)*(u-240)**7-1.4751*10**(-8)*(u-240)**6+0.0000131034*(u-240)**5-0.00642452*(u-240)**4+1.87806*(u-240)**3-327.394*(u-240)**2-1.207824*10**28*(u-240)-1.2924*10**6)`
`x(u,v)=u`
`z(u,v)=v`

EDIT II:
I am trying to get something like this:
[image]
*I am not the author of this image, source: aarondig,pmndrs/react-three-fiber, [www.github.com](http://www.github.com)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "straight forward" using geometry nodes.

You just have to place a bunch of math nodes. But the counter part is that you can describe many math functions.

In the firt part, below, the node tree uses a curve defined in the wanted function domain in X and resampled to the calculation steps. Next, the "set position" node receives the calculus for Y and places each point accordingly. Last it is transformed to a mesh in order to give it thickness.

[image]

The calculus itself is simply the formula, using the coefficients given by the defined group inputs:

[image]

As a result, you have this setting where you can define the coef you want:

[image]

[image]

To obtain something like this:

[image]

I have changed the circle which was giving thickness by a simple line, then added a solidify modifier.

Corresponding blend file:
[image]

Comment: How could I convert that curve into 3D, so that it 'extends' into z-direction, like a curved plane with that function as a cut in xy plane?

Comment: can you add an illustration of what you mean?

Comment: so, you mean a plane shape that follows the curve?

Comment: Yes, a plane shape that follows the curve.

Comment: like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xXMd.png

Comment: Yes, like that.